# AWS VPC Endpoint timeout when connecting to private API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, aws-sam

I have an AWS service defined using an AWS SAM template.

I am trying to connect to a private API Gateway like so;

VPC Endpoint -> private API Gateway -> AWS Lambda

The requests to the VPC Endpoint hang / timeout and I can see the private API Gateway is not being hit.

I've tried a few variations of this configuration but haven't been able to get anything working.

The GET `https://{{api-gateway-id}}-{{vpc-endpoint-id}}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/login` requests timeout.

Here is my AWS SAM template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  my-sam-template

Resources:
  # API Gateway
  APIGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Type: PRIVATE
        VPCEndpointIds:
          - !Ref APIGatewayVPCEndpoint
      Auth:
        ResourcePolicy:
          CustomStatements:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal: "*"
              Action: execute-api:Invoke
              Resource:
                - execute-api:/*
            - Effect: Deny
              Principal: "*"
              Action: execute-api:Invoke
              Resource:
                - execute-api:/*
              Condition:
                StringNotEquals:
                  aws:SourceVpce: !Ref APIGatewayVPCEndpoint

  # VPC
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true

  VPCSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16

  APIGatewaySecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      GroupDescription: Allows access over 443 to a single VPC Security Group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  APIGatewayVPCEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PrivateDnsEnabled: true
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref VPCSubnet
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref APIGatewaySecurityGroup
      ServiceName: com.amazonaws.us-east-1.execute-api
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      VpcEndpointType: Interface


  # Lambdas
  GetUsersLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambdas/users_lambda
      Handler: main.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Events:
        Login:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /login
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref APIGateway
```

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("GET users/login", dict(event=event))
```

Comment: Where are you testing the endpoint from? Is an EC2 instance? In the template you have created the VPC and 1 private subnet with no IGW, no Nat Gateway, no SSM Endpoint, so the agent won't work, how are you testing?

Comment: I am testing it via Postman

Comment: A VPC endpoint is only used from within the AWS infrastructure

Comment: @Paolo you are correct.

Comment: @oisin097 right, so your postman testing won't work